# Varnish 3 , block or slow down users based on IP Address traffic

Tags: linux, varnish

Varnish version 3.0.7.

Is it possible to slow down connections if you detect a lot of traffic/connections from a particular IP address ? Any suggestions on how to do that? We also have haproxy so we could black hole IPs if we could generate a list on the fly somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haproxy has provisions for a "tarpit".  See the manual for eg. "src_http_req_rate()" and "http-request tarpit"

```
frontend the_FRONTEND
  acl SpeedyGonzalez src_http_req_rate() ge 200
  use_backend the_TARPIT if SpeedyGonzalez

backend the_TARPIT
  timeout tarpit 2s
  errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/error_429.http
  http-request tarpit
```